# MTの多言語化対応に関して

Tags: cms

商品販売サイトをMT(Movable Type)ですでに作成されている方から、依頼を受けてMTで多言語化をしようと思っています。しかし如何せん私が触ったことがなく、どのように実装すべきかわからないのですが、助言をいただけないでしょうか。また、参考となる本があればご紹介ください。MTのバージョンはMTのpro Pro version 5.12です。

Comment: StackOverflowへようこそ。StackOverflowでは具体的な回答がつけられる質問が推奨されます。
現在のご質問内容ですと、回答者により回答が異なり、また回答も長くなることが考えられます。
次の情報を参考にご質問の内容を検討してみてはいかがでしょうか？
[良い質問をするには?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)／
[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381)／
[～したいです。実装方法が分かりません。のような質問](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2036)／
[「コードが思い浮かびません」という質問はどう聞けばよいですか？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1688)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「すでに作成されている方」が拡張(?)された部分がLocalizationを意識して作っているならば
(MTのディレクトリ)/lib/MT/L10N/　配下に言語ファイルが定義されているはずです。
下記の様な形で、タグと表示される文字列が定義されています。
'New User Information:' => '新規登録ユーザー:',
それに従って拡張された部分のタグに言語を定義するのみとなります。

上記を使用せずに直接script側に表示文字列を書いている場合は、直接scriptを修正する必要があるので、
「すでに作成されている方」に修正部分を確認し、一つ一つ上記Localizationファイルに定義していく必要があります。